# JPA cannot find a newly created object

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I'm persisting a new object in JPA, and then want to asynchronously index it. Thus, I  create the object, persist it, flush the EntityManager, get the new id, and then invoke an async method to get the index running. Alas - the async method cannot retrieve the object from the database.

Storage Code:

```
em().persist(theDataset);        
// updates....        
theDataset = ctxt.em().merge(theDataset); // store last updates
ctxt.em().flush();
logger.info( "New dataset id is: " + theDataset.getId() ); // logs a valid id
indexSvc.asyncIndexDataset(theDataset.getId(), true)
```

Retrieval code:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> asyncIndexDataset(long datasetId, boolean doNormalSolrDocCleanUp) {
    Dataset toIndex = em.find(Dataset.class, datasetId);
    if ( toIndex == null ) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot find dataset with id {0}", datasetId);
        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    } else {
        return indexDataset(toIndex, doNormalSolrDocCleanUp);
    }
}
```

Result log:

```
[2018-04-10T17:41:39.275+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1523371299275] [levelValue: 800] [[
  New dataset id is: 20]]

[2018-04-10T17:41:39.305+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=175 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool10] [timeMillis: 1523371299305] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Cannot find dataset with id 20]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Flushing the entity manager is not enough. It means that all the changes recorded in the entity manager will be sent out to the database. 
Despite this fact, it doesn't mean that other readers can read the changes. This is depending on the isolation level of the database.

I think your problem is that, the reader (the index service in another thread) is going to the DB to read the newly persisted entity, however the original transaction (which you persisted the entity) is not finished yet, thus the reader cannot find it.

I'd say let's finish your transaction first, then try to index it, or even better if you can just simply pass the persisted object into the index service (considering that no change would happen to the entity on DB side).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting insights. It's a fairly large project, which uses container transaction management, so I'm not sure I can commit the transaction when I want (can I?). As for the index service, it has to go to the database for other related objects, so passing the persisted object does not work - I just bump into the same problem later in the process.